# Request Geolocation permission again after user denies

Tags: permissions, geolocation

I am developing a website in which it is sort of a nono not to share your geolocation. So I was wondering if it is possible to ask the users a 2nd time for their permission to share their geolocation or for the users to manually click a button to give their permission or something like that.
I can imagine that as a user you don't want to share your geolocation the first time you visit a website, but you should be able to alter it when you're familiar with the concept.

Any other suggestions in resolving this issue are obviously welcome as well

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There is no way out because when the user opts not to share the geolocation,browser settings changes and it won't ask further for the geolocation.
User can do it manually changing the settings.
From UI perspective you can add a modal showing that the user has disabled geolocation sharing and make the user go to the settings to change the browser preference.

Answer (score -2):

```
function getLocation(){
   if (navigator.geolocation){
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
   }
   else{
       message ="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
   }
}

<button onclick="getLocation()">Get Location</button>
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't allow me to revise my permission. It just recalculates my location but if I denied permission the first time then it will not ask me if I want to reconsider my permissions.